# Fill up previous stars on a JQuery 5-star rating onmouseover system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a 5 star rating system and fill up the stars left from the mouseover position yellow (class called `yellow`), otherwise `grey`.

I have done this so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="stars3">
<i data-count="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey"></i> 
<i data-count="1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey"></i> 
<i data-count="2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey"></i> 
<i data-count="3" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey"></i> 
<i data-count="4" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey"></i> 
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("[id^=stars] > i").hover(function() {
    count = $(this).attr("data-count");
    $(this).each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).attr("data-count") < count)
        $(this).addClass("yellow");
    });
    console.log($(this));
});
```

But this only fills one single star to yellow. I need to select and fill all previous single `<i>` elements somehow. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c25qt20d/). Is this what were you looking for ?

```
$("#stars3 > i").hover(function() {
$(this).prevAll().addClass('yellow').removeClass('grey')
$(this).addClass('yellow').removeClass('grey')
$(this).nextAll().addClass('grey').removeClass('yellow')
});
```

Comment: you're welcome. please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
$("[id^=stars] > i").hover(function() {
  $(this).prevAll().addBack().toggleClass("yellow");
});
```

```css
.yellow { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stars3">
    <i data-count="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey">*</i> 
    <i data-count="1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey">*</i> 
    <i data-count="2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey">*</i> 
    <i data-count="3" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey">*</i> 
    <i data-count="4" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star grey-light grey">*</i> 
    </div>
```